# Implementing a rethrowing function

Tags: swift, error-handling, try-catch, throw

I'm implementing a helper method for CoreData

```
public func doInMain(_ block: (NSManagedObjectContext) -> Void) {
    guard let context = mainQueueContext else { return }
    context.performAndWait({
        block(context)
    })
}
```

It works well and can be called like this:

```
CoreDataManager().doInMain { moc in
    // do your fetch request with managed object context
}
```

But it's very annoying when I want to try an error in `doInMain` block, because it can't be rethrowed by the calling function. Since the bloc is `nonescaping`, it should be done.

So I added:

```
public func doInMain(_ block: (NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> Void) rethrows {
    guard let context = mainQueueContext else { return }
    context.performAndWait({
        try block(context)
    })
}
```

But NSManagedObjectContext.performAndWait do not rethrows errors, so it won't compile.

It tryed this:

```
public func doInMain(_ block: (NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> Void) rethrows {
    guard let context = mainQueueContext else { return }
    var thrownError: Error?
    context.performAndWait({
        do { try block(context) }
        catch { thrownError = error }
    })
    if let error = thrownError {
        throw error
    }
}
```

But now the compiler says `A function declared 'rethrows' may only throw if its parameter does`

Am I screwed up? Is there a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: I think you are screwed :) why not changing to `public func doInMain(_ block: @escaping (NSManagedObjectContext?, Error?) -> Void) {
        guard let context = mainQueueContext else { return }
        context.performAndWait({
            block(context, nil)
        })
    }`

Comment: Cause I don't want my method to be `@esccaping`! `performAndWait` is not, so my method should be considered synchronous by the compiler. It really simplifies using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely ideal, but one option would be to just write two overloads – one that takes a closure that doesn't throw and itself doesn't throw, and another that takes a throwing closure and itself throws.

For example:

```
public func doInMain(_ block: (NSManagedObjectContext) -> Void) {
  guard let context = mainQueueContext else { return }
  context.performAndWait {
    block(context)
  }
}

public func doInMain(_ block: (NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> Void) throws {
  guard let context = mainQueueContext else { return }
  var thrownError: Error?
  context.performAndWait {
    do {
      try block(context)
    } catch {
      thrownError = error
    }
  }
  if let error = thrownError {
    throw error
  }
}
```

Bear in mind that if desired, you could always implement the non-throwing overload in terms of the throwing overload:

```
public func doInMain(_ block: (NSManagedObjectContext) -> Void) {
  let fn = doInMain as ((NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> Void) throws -> Void
  try! fn(block)
}
```

You should be able to use both overloads in much the same way as a single rethrowing overload.

Comment: Not entirely ideal, but it does the job. Since `performAndWait` don't rethrow I think there is no better solution. Thanks, i didn't know we could override by changing the way methods throw errors.

Answer (score 1):

in **iOS 15** there is new [performAndWait](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/3802019-performandwait) method available which does allow rethrowing.

```
func performAndWait<T>(_ block: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T
```

Comment: Thanks Apple, at last !